# Specified cast is not valid.In VS2015 c# getting data from a sql

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I have a SQL with this columns and the class with de info of the data in the sql (in VS):

[image]

the class that makes a List:

[image]

here is the problem, when a execute this lasts commands VS say: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

this happen with the lines:

```
pt3.datetime = reader.GetDateTime(5);

pt3.time= reader.GetTimeSpan(7);

pt3.test_time = reader.GetInt32(8);

pt3.no_load_current_ext = reader.GetDecimal(10);
```

I think is the SQL but it looks fine, and i try to change the type, but that nnot work

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, *post the actual code*.

Comment: Where is the sql query? You are really asking us to help to fix the sql query without even showing it?

Comment: Please show the exact exception and stack trace.  It should tell you which of those four lines the exception occurred on.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL returns all columns, then you've forgot the order_nbr. In other words, you're reading wrong data since item #3 (error_code).

Comment: Oh! thanks . i know the other guys are upset about the "style" of the question, im new here, and i guessed that will be enought for you guys. Sorry for that.